# How to apply the same transformation to groups of variables in a data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data frame with lots of variables whose names include tags.

```r
mydf <- data.frame(
    var_x = 1:5, var_y = runif(5), var_z = runif(5), 
    other_x = 10:14, other_p = runif(5), other_r = runif(5)
    )
mydf
  var_x     var_y      var_z other_x   other_p   other_r
1     1 0.2700212 0.05893272      10 0.6212327 0.6177092
2     2 0.1284033 0.27333098      11 0.6933060 0.7520978
3     3 0.7313771 0.69352560      12 0.3154764 0.8479646
4     4 0.2400357 0.25151053      13 0.2057361 0.5138406
5     5 0.1797793 0.78550584      14 0.6671606 0.5801830
```

I would like to divide `var_*` variables by `var_x` and `other_*` variables with `other_x`. How can I do this easily?

I tried to use `mutate_each` of `dplyr`. The following works if there is only one group to scale. How can I automate this to each tag?

```r
library(dplyr)
scale_var <- mydf$var_x
mydf %>% mutate_each(funs(./scale_var), matches("^var"))
```

---

I tried to write my own function as follows.

```r
mymutate <- function(data, type) {
  scale_var <- mydf[[paste0(type, "_x")]]
  data %>% mutate_each(
    funs(./scale_var), 
    matches(paste0("^", type))
  )
}
```

But when I tried to run it on just one type `mymutate(mydf, type = "var")` it threw an error that I do not really understand: `Error in paste0("^", type) : object 'type' not found`

---

**UPDATE**

I would like to use only the new variables, so it does not matter that the method divides the `x` variables by themselves as well.

I have a lots of such tags as `var` and `other` so I do not want to write them out in each case. That is why I tried to construct my own function to use it later with `lapply`.

**UPDATE2**

These are the variables of my data frame.

```r
 [1] "location_50_all_1"                  "location_50_both_sides_important_1"
 [3] "location_50_left_important_1"       "location_50_other_important_1"     
 [5] "location_50_right_important_1"      "ownership_all_1"                   
 [7] "ownership_both_sides_important_1"   "ownership_left_important_1"        
 [9] "ownership_other_important_1"        "ownership_right_important_1"       
[11] "person_all_1"                       "person_both_sides_important_1"     
[13] "person_left_important_1"            "person_other_important_1"          
[15] "person_right_important_1"           "union_all_1"                       
[17] "union_both_sides_important_1"       "union_left_important_1"            
[19] "union_other_important_1"            "union_right_important_1"           
[21] "total_left_important"               "total_right_important"             
[23] "total_both_sides_important"         "total_other_important"             
[25] "total_firm_officials"               "left"                              
[27] "right"                              "connected"
```

I would like to divide `location_50*` variables by `location_50_all_1` and the same for `location_200*`, `ownership*`, `person*`, `union*`.

**UPDATE3**

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28988004/r-dplyrs-mutate-each-within-function-works-but-matches-does-not-find-argumen#28988390) is the answer to the question why `'type' not found`.

Comment: Are you sure `mydf %>% mutate_each(funs(./var_x), matches("^var"))` is giving you the desired result?

Comment: @JasonAizkalns You are right, that does not work. I updated the question accordingly. The `x` variable is going to be updated by ones after dividing it by itself, so later I would divide the other variables just by one. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. I believe the posted solutions (so far) work as intended.

Comment: I don't see how they allow for `lapply`... Maybe with some tweaking. Although I still do not understand why I get the error message that `'type' not found`

Comment: How does your real data look like? Do you have three columns for each variable name just like your sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This modified version of `mymutate` would work even if the data frame is not nicely structured (that is the number of columns which should be scaled is not the same for each case).

```r
# mydf
#   var_x     var_y     var_z other_x     other_p    other_r
# 1     1 0.1913353 0.4706113      10 0.003120607 0.17808048
# 2     2 0.1620725 0.6228830      11 0.844399758 0.01361841
# 3     3 0.5148884 0.3671178      12 0.996055741 0.33513972
# 4     4 0.8086168 0.3265216      13 0.984819261 0.96802056
# 5     5 0.9902217 0.9087540      14 0.951119864 0.82479090

mymutate <- function(data, type) {
  scale_var <- data[[paste0(type, "_x")]]
  data %<>% 
    select(matches(paste0("^", type))) %>%
    mutate_each(funs(./scale_var))
  data[[paste0(type, "_x")]] <- scale_var
  data
}

types <- c("var", "other")
lapply(types, mymutate, data=mydf) %>% bind_cols(.)

#   var_x      var_y      var_z other_x      other_p     other_r
# 1     1 0.19133528 0.47061133      10 0.0003120607 0.017808048
# 2     2 0.08103626 0.31144148      11 0.0767636144 0.001238037
# 3     3 0.17162946 0.12237259      12 0.0830046451 0.027928310
# 4     4 0.20215421 0.08163039      13 0.0757553278 0.074463120
# 5     5 0.19804435 0.18175081      14 0.0679371332 0.058913635
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be helpful. If you have three columns for each variable name (e.g., three columns with 'var' and three columns with 'other'), I'd use `lapply()`. Then, bind columns to go back to the original data format, if necessary.

```
# mydf
#  var_x     var_y     var_z other_x    other_p    other_r
#1     1 0.8393539 0.2685360      10 0.82749405 0.77923222
#2     2 0.8966534 0.6157903      11 0.30657267 0.97301619
#3     3 0.7426782 0.6982445      12 0.75195632 0.03107233
#4     4 0.9448537 0.3711827      13 0.68455120 0.45232667
#5     5 0.4848614 0.2108115      14 0.01126723 0.91213041

library(dplyr)

num <- seq(1, ncol(mydf), 3)

lapply(num, function(x) mydf[, x:(x+2)]) -> foo
lapply(foo, function(y) {y[,2] = y[, 2] / y[, 1]
                         y[,3] = y[, 3] / y[, 1]
                         y}) %>%
bind_cols(.)

#  var_x      var_y      var_z other_x      other_p     other_r
#1     1 0.83935391 0.26853595      10 0.0827494049 0.077923222
#2     2 0.44832669 0.30789516      11 0.0278702429 0.088456017
#3     3 0.24755938 0.23274817      12 0.0626630264 0.002589361
#4     4 0.23621343 0.09279569      13 0.0526577848 0.034794359
#5     5 0.09697229 0.04216230      14 0.0008048022 0.065152172
```

Comment: Thanks, this sounds good. I'll give it a try. Any idea why `'type' not found`?

Comment: @janosdivenyi Not sure what is happening. I just think that mutate_each is not the way to go. Seeing your own function, I think you are asking R to pick up three columns each time and do mutate_each. If you have hundreds of columns, I guess you would apply your functions using lapply to a for loop. If so, splitting your data and employ lapply seems to be a good way.

Comment: Yes, this solution works if the data frame is nicely structured as in this example. Just one remark: `bind.cols()` is not part of `dplyr`, but `do.call(cbind, .)` instead works as intended.

Comment: @janosdivenyi I meant `bind_cols()`. I am sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are after...

```
library(dplyr)

mydf <- data.frame(
  var_x = 1:5, var_y = runif(5), var_z = runif(5), 
  other_x = 10:14, other_p = runif(5), other_r = runif(5)
)

my_df_var <-
  mydf %>% 
  select(contains("var")) 

my_divided_var_df <-
  my_df_var / my_df_var[, 1]

my_df_other <-
  mydf %>% 
  select(contains("other")) 

my_divided_other_df <-
  my_df_other / my_df_other[, 1]

my_final_df <-
  bind_cols(my_divided_var_df, 
            my_divided_other_df)

my_final_df
  var_x     var_y      var_z other_x    other_p    other_r
1     1 0.1505216 0.50006694       1 0.01507284 0.04272813
2     1 0.3694496 0.07608916       1 0.03721775 0.07758692
3     1 0.1615257 0.05903999       1 0.04790595 0.00702291
4     1 0.1867266 0.15325190       1 0.06612689 0.03709427
5     1 0.1823187 0.15005917       1 0.02325902 0.05880811
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var_x_orig <- mydf$var_x
other_x_orig <- mydf$other_x

mydf %>%
  mutate_each(funs(./var_x_orig), matches("^var")) %>%
  mutate_each(funs(./other_x_orig), matches("^other"))
```