# dplyr's mutate_each within function works but matches() does not find argument

Tags: r, dplyr

When trying to solve [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28964929/r-how-to-apply-the-same-transformation-to-groups-of-variables-in-a-data-frame) I encountered a problem with `mutate_each` of `dplyr`. I wanted to use it within a function and pass arguments to it. It was successful for `funs()` but not for `matches()`.

Let me show a simple example where the task is to append some tag the values of some variables.

```r
library(dplyr) 
mydf <- data.frame(this_var1 = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), 
                   this_var2 = c("b", "c", "d", "e", "f"),
                   that_var1 = c("x", "y", "z", "w", "u"))

mymutate1 <- function(data, tag) {
  data %>% mutate_each(funs(paste0(., tag)))
}

mymutate1(mydf, "_foo")
  this_var1 this_var2 that_var1
1     a_foo     b_foo     x_foo
2     b_foo     c_foo     y_foo
3     c_foo     d_foo     z_foo
4     d_foo     e_foo     w_foo
5     e_foo     f_foo     u_foo
```

This works like a charm. However, if I try to control also for which variables the transformation should be applied it fails.

```r
mymutate2 <- function(data, tag, m) {
  data %>% mutate_each(funs(paste0(., tag)), matches(m))
}
mymutate2(mydf, "_foo", "this")
```

This gives the following error: `Error in is.string(match) : object 'm' not found`. Why is `tag` found whereas `m` not?

The code itself works as intended:

```r
mydf %>% mutate_each(funs(paste0(., "_foo")), matches("this"))
  this_var1 this_var2 that_var1
1     a_foo     b_foo         x
2     b_foo     c_foo         y
3     c_foo     d_foo         z
4     d_foo     e_foo         w
5     e_foo     f_foo         u
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are going to want to use the [Standard Evaluation (SE)](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html) version of `mutate_each` -- that is, `mutate_each_`:

```
mymutate2 <- function(data, tag, m) {
  data %>% mutate_each_(funs(paste0(., tag)), ~matches(m))
}
```

For additional clarity, the following is equivalent:

```
mymutate3 <- function(data, tag, m) {
  data %>% mutate_each_(~paste0(., tag), ~matches(m))
}
```

And per the [vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html):

*"It’s best to use a formula [ `~` as opposed to `quote()` or using strings `""` ], because a formula captures both the expression to evaluate, and the environment in which it should be a evaluated...Using anything other than a formula will fail because it doesn't know which environment to look in."*